# How to increase the timeout for `yarn install`

Tags: download, connection, yarnpkg

I'm currently using Yarn on a very unstable internet connection.
Sometimes it takes hours until I can finally download all the packages.

I noticed Yarn retries the download when there is some kind of the internet connection:

```
[1/4] Resolving packages...
31-Dec-1969 21:00:00    [INFO] info There appears to be trouble with your 
network connection. Retrying...
31-Dec-1969 21:00:00    [ERROR] error An unexpected error occurred: 
"https://github.com/flot/flot: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN github.com:443".
```

Is it possible to retry forever until it downloads or increase the timeout?

Something like `{timeout: 9999999}`

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Try using the `network-timeout` flag with a delay in milliseconds, like this:

`yarn install --network-timeout 1000000000`

Comment: can i set it at global level or this will work only for current yarn install?

Comment: As far as I know there is no global setting for this I'm afraid. :|

Comment: okie.. i got new windows, after installing new window this is happening before that it was working

Comment: still getting a "Timeout awaiting 'socket' for 60000ms" error even using this command (yarn 3.2.1). Maybe I'll open a new question...

Answer (score 31):

You can configure it with this:

```
yarn config set network-timeout 600000 -g
```

Newer version of yarn use this:

```
yarn config set httpTimeout 600000
```

Comment: Haven't tried this myself but if it does work as it suggests, then this should become the accepted answer. Out of curiosity, is there any documentation about this on Yarn's website? Does it work with Yarn 2 only or was it always sitting there?

Comment: it doesn't come up from yarn --help, but there is a docs page: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/config/

Comment: Newer versions of yarn use `yarn config set httpTimeout 600000` - https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/pull/1291

Comment: @Jaybird have you confirmed that, should i update the answer?